# Compare two dataframes and update the dataframe if the data is different

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes df1, df2, df2 contains updated information, df1 is the old data obtained from database. So, we are trying to create new dataframes df3, df4.
df3(should contain new records(ids)) , df4(should contain modified records)

example:

df1 =

id   Name   score
111  Jack   2.17
112  Nick   1.11
113  Zoe    4.12

df2 =

id   Name   score
111  Jack   2.17
112  ***Sick   1.10***
113  Zoe    4.12
**114  Jay    12.3**

So, I need a new dataframe df3 (new id) say,

df3 =

id   Name   score
114  Jay    12.3

I need a new dataframe df4 (same id different data) say,

df4 =

id   Name   score
112  Sick   1.10

How can this be acheived?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the logic correctly . . .

```
# imports
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

# sample data
s1 = """id Name score
111 Jack 2.17
112 Nick 1.11
113 Zoe 4.12"""

s2 = """id Name score
111 Jack 2.17
112 Sick 1.10
113 Zoe 4.12
114 Jay 12.3"""

df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s1), sep=' ')
df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s2), sep=' ')

# use boolean indexing with isin
# new id in df2 that is not in df1
df3 = df2[~df2['id'].isin(df1['id'])]
# where id is the same but name or score is different
# also does not include the data where id is in the newly created df3
df4 = df2[~(df2[['Name', 'score']].isin(df1[['Name', 'score']]).any(1) | df2['id'].isin(df3['id']))]
```

df3

```
    id Name  score
3  114  Jay   12.3
```

df4

```
    id  Name  score
1  112  Sick    1.1
```